# Си,поиск слова в строке

Tags: c, строки, сравнение

Суть задания: "*Вывести порядковые номера слов в строке, совпадающих с введенным словом"*.

Вопрос в том, как сравнить введённое слово со словом в строке, т.е. как перебрать всю строку и найти то самое совпадающее слово.

Answer (score 1):

**C++ & STL:**

```
std::string word = ...;
std::string str = ...;

std::string::size_type pos = 0;
while ((pos = str.find(word, pos)) != std::string::npos) {
    std::cout << "Found!" << std::endl;
    pos += word.length();
}
```

**C**

```
const char *const word = ...;
const char *const str = ...;

const char* p = str;
while ((p = strstr(str, word)) != NULL) {
    printf("Found!\n");
    p += strlen(word);
}
```

Comment: Полагаю, ответ с использованием STL не примут.

Comment: @gbg Да пофиг! Всё равно закроют! ;-)

Comment: Предвижу следующий вопрос: определить порядковый номер слова в строке. ;-)

Comment: Полагаю, вопрос будет - почему у меня в C С++ не работает.